# how to mixte find -printf and wc -l to create a CSV with files Metadata and number of lines per file

Tags: bash, find, wc

I need to collect some data from files:

```
/usr$ find . -type f -fprintf /tmp/out.csv "%f | %h | %k | %p\n"
/usr$ head -2 /tmp/out.csv 
gettext | ./share/sensible-utils/bin | 4 | ./share/sensible-utils/bin/gettext
inherits_browser.js | ./share/javascript/inherits | 4 | ./share/javascript/inherits/inherits_browser.js
/usr$
```

On the sames files (in real life this files are CSV) I collect the number of lines with:

```
/usr$ find . -type f |while read i;do wc -l "$i"  ;done > /tmp/out.csv
/usr$ head /tmp/out.csv
3 ./share/sensible-utils/bin/gettext
27 ./share/javascript/inherits/inherits_browser.js
17 ./share/javascript/typedarray-to-buffer/index.js
0 ./share/javascript/typedarray-to-buffer/index.min.js
297 ./share/javascript/sphinxdoc/1.0/language_data.js
316 ./share/javascript/sphinxdoc/1.0/doctools.js
26 ./share/javascript/sphinxdoc/1.0/theme_extras.js
514 ./share/javascript/sphinxdoc/1.0/searchtools.js
158 ./share/javascript/sphinxdoc/1.0/sidebar.js
1 ./share/javascript/sphinxdoc/1.0/css3-mediaqueries.js
/usr$
```

How could I produce an `/tmp/out.csv` file with all the columns from the `-fprintf` plus one with the output of `wc -l` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
find /path -type f -exec sh -c '
  for f; do total=$(wc -l < "$f"); printf "%s|" "$total"
done' sh {} \; -printf '%f|%h|%k|%p\n'
```

---

- See [Understanding the -exec option to find](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705/understanding-the-exec-option-of-find)

Comment: look like it work, but i don't understand why ;) the quote after -c isn't closed on the first quote of '%s' ?

Comment: It is closed just after the `done`.